# Windows 7 pro, edit group rights

Tags: windows-7

How can I change the rights of a local group in Windows 7? For example, I have created a new group and I want all members of that group to have remote desktop access.

I can go to Computer Management/Local Users and Groups and edit the properties of the new group but the only available option is to edit the member list.

Obviously I can add each user to the Remote Desktop group but this seems to be defeating the basic purpose of groups. The group defines a particular role and that role requires (amongst other things) remote desktop access.

I vaguely remember a version of Windows (NT 4.0, perhaps) where this was a straightforward operation, and the existence of predefined groups with different properties suggests that it is still possible, but so far I have not been able to find the tool to do it.

After investigation I have found what should be the answer to my question:

Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Local Security Policy/Local Policies/User Rights Assignment

This gives a list of rights and allows me to assign them to the group that I have created. I have tested this by giving the group the "Change the system time" right. This works exactly as I expected, a user that is a member of the group can now change the time where formerly it could not.

However, giving the group the "Allow logon through remote desktop services" does not work. The login attempt fails with insufficient privileges. If the user is a member of the remote desktop group then it succeeds. I cannot see any significant difference between the built in remote desktop group, which works, and the group I have created, which does not.

In case this is significant the remote client is xfreerdp 2.0.0-rc4, Windows runs under qemu, all on one machine. Running mstsc from a second Windows VM also fails with "user account is not authorized for remote login". Assigning the right directly to the user also fails

Comment: This can be done with a group policy.  The straight forward operation you are thinking of is likely simply using the local group policy editor.

Comment: You are asking for something that doesn't exist. You didn't like my answer so I deleted it.

Comment: @harrymc You may be correct in saying that what I want does not exist, at least with respect to remote desktop (see the additions to my question). I chose remote desktop as a generic example of what I wanted to achieve and by mischance it doesn't work, had I chosen "change system time" instead then that would have worked, so had you still said "it can't be done" then you would have been wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Open Control Panel. In the category view choose "System and Security".

Choose "Administrative Tools" then double click "Local Security Policy".

In the left pane expand "Local Policies", now click "User rights assignment". This will fill the right pane with a list of rights and the users and groups that have been granted those rights. Double click the right that you want to grant or revoke. This will give a list of users and groups that currently have that right, with buttons to add or remove. Note that if you want to grant a right to a group then you must first click the "Object types" button then select the "Groups" checkbox.

Note that for reasons that I have yet to determine, granting the remote desktop right does not work. The user or group will appear in the list but the right will not be granted.

Comment: I was able to find the Administrator user group without an issue.  In the specific case of Remote Desktop, you are adding user groups you wish to deny access, not grant access to.  In my limited testing, adding a user group to the policy, granted/denied permission to the user in the user group.